# Connect Bluetooth 4.0 Headset

Tags: sound, bluetooth, 19.04

I am trying to connect my bluetooth headset.

Jabra Talk 45

Specs:

Bluetooth® compliance Bluetooth® version 4.0

Supported Bluetooth® profiles Advanced Audio Distribution (A2DP) v1.2, AVRCP ABS only. Hands-free profile v1.6,
headset profile v1.2, phone book access profile (PBAB) v1.0

Supported modes EDR (2 and 3 Mb), SCO, eSCO, sniff mode

It is not shown in the list of devices.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check user manual of "Jabra Talk 45" to make your device discoverable/connectable after powering it ON.
Once your headphones is in discoverable mode, it will be listed on the device list of your computer/smart-phone(any source device)

Once your "Jabra Talk 45" is visible, you can click on it to pair with your source device.
(Usually an LED keeps blinking when it is discoverable and gets steady after getting connected successfully)

Cheers if it helped! :)

Comment: omg..., rtfm... ;)